# Is virtual dispatch used if class type is known?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, vtable

Suppose we have base class `A` with at least one virtual method. Suppose then we have another class `B` that derives from `A` and may or may not override this virtual method.

Finally, suppose you create an object of class `B` with local scope, and call this virtual method.

From the C++ docs we know that if this virtual method is inlined, the inline version will be used, because class type is known and this is not pointer or reference, but the class itself.

Will virtual dispatch be used in this case or it will be bypassed? Will this work for normal (non inline) methods?

I am interested in gcc / clang.

Comment: C++ has no concept of a _vtable_, that's compiler implementation specific.

Comment: thanks. question updated with gcc tag

Comment: If you create B on the stack, then the compiler knows exactly what type it is, so it doesn't need to go through the vtable. Just beware of the slicing problem, if you're passing the object around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both the stack and the vtable are implementation details, it's probably better to phrase it:

> Can the compiler use static - rather than virtual - dispatch if the object's (real, runtime) type is statically known?

to which the answer is: yes. Anywhere the compiler knows for certain what version of a virtual method will be used, it can just emit a regular statically-dispatched function call.

Note that there are some places you might *expect* the compiler to know the object's runtime type and be mistaken - specifically inside constructors.

If you want to know whether a particular compiler *does* emit this particular optimization for some particular code (*at a particular optimization level*), just check the assembly output. Even if you're not sure what both versions of a call should look like, you can compare the output with a simple and a fully-qualified call (`b.B::foo() vs b.foo()`). I'd expect gcc and clang to do a reasonable job in this case, but it's easy enough to check.

Comment: When checking, do so at both -O0 and -O2. Devirtualization is technically an optimization.